# How to use Teambox REST API for uploading files

Tags: java, json, rest, social-networking

Below I am pasting content from `Teambox api` documentation:
https://teambox.com/api/upload

```
uploads#create POST

/api/1/projects/:project_id/uploads

/api/1/uploads
```

Creates a new upload. Note that you will need to post an upload using form encoding for this to work.

```
Parameters you should pass
{
  "page_id": 456,
  "project_id": 123,
  "name": "Name",
  "asset": "<File Data>"
}
```

Questions:

1. What do we mean by *upload using form encoding*?
2. What does *asset: `<File Data>`* represent?

Any code example would be great too. Thanks

Comment: Read up on stuff at hc.apache.org for a discussion of different ways to POST

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have to *post* data to teambox in your call. 
[image: smiley]

POST is one of the methods commonly used by web forms, when passing data to a server.
[This "official" link tells what is what](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

First described manners describe a call thought as a **GET** request.
Latest form you get takes the shape of a **POST** call.

You can build a **POST call** in many ways, depending on the native language your client app uses.
If is a **javascript** based web app, you can use **XHTTPRequest** object which resides on browsers.
If your app runs in a Linux based system, maybe you can use libraries that allow you build-up that call, such **cURL** library.

So, can you show the code or get deeper in your description? 
Would be nice to know your environment and programming language.